# Curl command uploading document fails when run from Perl

Tags: perl, curl

I've got a Perl script that uploads documents into Alfresco using curl.

Some of the documents have ampersand in the file name and initially this caused curl to fail. I fixed this by placing a carat symbol in front of the ampersand. But now I'm finding some documents are failing to upload when they don't have a space either side of the ampersand.  Other documents with spaces in the file name and an ampersand do load successfully.

The snippet of Perl code that is running is:

> ```
>           # Escape & for curl in file name with a ^
>             my $downloadFileNameEsc = ${downloadfile};
>             $downloadFileNameEsc =~ s/&/^&/g;
>             $command = "curl -u admin:admin -F file=\@${downloadFileNameEsc} -F id=\"${docId}\" -F title=\"${docTitle}\" -F tags=\"$catTagStr\" -F abstract=\"${abstract}\" -F published=\"${publishedDate}\" -F pubId=\"${pubId}\" -F pubName=\"${pubName}\" -F modified=\"${modifiedDate}\" -F archived=\"${archived}\" -F expiry=\"${expiryDate}\" -F groupIds=\"${groupIdStr}\" -F groupNames=\"${groupNameStr}\" ${docLoadUrl}";
> ```

```
            logmsg(4, $command);
            my @cmdOutput = `$command`;
            $exitStatus = $?;
            my $upload = 0;
            logmsg(4, "Alfresco upload status $exitStatus");
            if ($exitStatus != 0) {
```

You can see that I am using backticks to execute the curl command so that I can read the response.  The perl script is being run under windows.

What this effectively tries to run is:

curl -u admin:admin -F file=@tmp-download/Multiple%20Trusts%20Gift%20^&%20Loan.pdf -F id="e2ef104d-b4be-4896-8360-7d6f2e7c7b72" ....
This works.

curl -u admin:admin -F file=@tmp-download/Quarterly_Buys^&sells_Q1_2006.doc -F id="78d18634-ee93-4c29-b01d-270aeee3219a" ....
This fails!!

The only difference being as far as I can see is that in the one that works the file name has spaces (%26) in the file name somewhere around the ampersand, not necessarily next to the ampersand.

I can't see why one runs successfully and the other doesn't.  Think it must be to do with backticks and ampersands in the file name. I haven't tried using system as I wanted to capture the response.

Any thoughts because I've exhausted all options.

Comment: Why are you using an external `curl` call instead of `LWP`?

Comment: If you really think you must use `curl`, then instead of backticks use something like `IPC::Run`, `capturex` from `IPC::System::Simple`, or a "pipe-open", so you avoid all the problems with special shell characters.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn to use Perl modules. Perl has some great modules to handle the Web requests. If you depend upon operating system commands, you will end up with not only dependencies upon those commands, but shell interactions and whether or not you need to quote special characters.

Perl modules remove a lot of the issues that you can run into. You are no longer dependent upon particular commands or even particular implementation of those commands. (The `curl` command can vary from system to system, and may not even be on the system you're on). Plus, most of these modules handle the piddling details for you (such as URI escaping strings).

[LWP](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) is the standard Perl library for implementing these requests. Take a look at the [LWP Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/lwpcook.pod). This is a tutorial on the whole HTTP process. Basically, you need to create an *agent* which is really just a virtual web browser for you to use. Then, you can configure it (for example, setting the machine, browser type, etc.) you might need.

What is really nice is [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon) that provides a simple interface for using HTTP forms.

```
my $results = POST "$docLoadUrl"
   [ file       => '@' . "$downloadFileName",
     id         => $docId,
     title      => $docTitle,
     tag        => $catTagStr,
     abstract   => $abstract,
     published  => $publishedDate,
     pubId      => $pubId,
     pubName    => $pubName,
     ...
   ];
```

This is a lot easier to read and maintain. Plus, it will handle URI encoding for you.